# Your firewall blocks traffic on websocket ports error on online service

Tags: websocket, firewall, leon

I'm working with Leon verification system online at http://leon.epfl.ch/. I'm having problems with the connection with the following errors:

> Failed to connect: Leon failed to contact the mothership :( It usually
>   indicates that your firewall blocks traffic on websocket ports.
>
> Failed to connect: The Leon server appears to be unreachable right
>   now.

Is there any way I can solve this kind of problem on my own?

Comment: Try the alternative URL http://leondev.epfl.ch/.

Comment: @larsrh Uaou!! Why is this one working?

Comment: I have no idea. I vaguely remember that leondev runs on a beefier machine and maybe nobody is around to manage the machine which runs leon-non-dev.